# PowerShell: How can I handle current object from a csv.file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to install some programs according to the current operating system on a computer. My .csv file looks like this:

```
OperatingSystem, Program
Microsoft Windows 7, Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise, Skype
Microsoft Windows 7, Oracle Client
Windows XP, Skype
Windows XP, Adobe Reader
```

I wrote this piece of code:

```
##Determine OperatingSystem
$os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem  
$a = $os | % {$_.caption}

##Programs needed to be installed
$test=import-csv "C:\Documents and Settings\Nistru\Desktop\Kituri\Fisier.txt." |
                where-object {$_.OperatingSystem -like "Microsoft Windows 7*"} |
                select-object Program
```

Is there any way that I can check in where-object block if `$_.OperatingSystem` is equal to variable `$a`, so that I don't have to write the code for each operating system all over again?

Comment: Start by reading `help ForEach-Object`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That isn't helpful, he needs assistance with his `Where` statement more than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily just replace your string "Microsoft Windows 7" with your variable `$a` - though I don't think that is exactly what you mean. You are using the `-like` operator and have a `*` in the hard-coded string so I would imagine you are looking for any version of Win7 - a slightly more complex problem. Here is a suggestion:

Modify your input CSV file to (optionally) contain the wildcard. It will work just fine in your comparison and you would change the `Where-Object` cmdlet to be something like:

```
Import-CSV Fisier.txt | ? { $os.Caption -like $_.OperatingSystem }
```

The `-like` operator without a wildcard character will treat the comparison basically the same as an equals so it can be used for explicit operating system matches as well. Just be sure to include the `*` where you want a match regardless of the edition.

Sidenote: I am not sure why you are piping the `$os` variable through the `For-EachObject` operator only to select out the caption property. Simply referencing it as a property should be sufficient: `$os.Caption`

Here is the script (and output) I checked against using the modified CSV with wildcards:

```
PS C:\>$os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem
PS C:\>Import-CSV Fisier.txt | ? { $os.Caption -like $_.OperatingSystem }
OperatingSystem        Program
---------------        -------
Microsoft Windows 7*   Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft Windows*     Oracle Client
```

and CSV file:

```
OperatingSystem, Program
Microsoft Windows 7*, Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise, Skype
Microsoft Windows*, Oracle Client
Windows XP, Skype
Windows XP, Adobe Reader
```

Comment: I removed the pipe for $os, you are right. Actually, I do want to replace the string "Microsoft Windows 7" with variable $a. The variable $a will have different values according to the operating system installed. But if I simply replace the string with $a, my $test variable returns nothing :( I tried to change the operators with -eq, -match, -contains, but still nothing...am I doing something wrong? I really don't understand why it doesn't work...maybe $_.OperatingSystem and $a (which is $os.caption) have different types and I can't compare them? Sorry I keep bothering you!

Comment: Now it works just fine, the variable $test returns what I want! Thank you!